# Failed to resolve module specifier, firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to fix an issue with an old firebase app. and im trying to update the app to 8. I dont want to use 9 yet because i want to use the old code as much as possible. With that in mind everything is in an html page. And when I import the new libraries I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

But this is pretty much exactly as the tutorial asks me to implement the code. I looked at other SO's here but its all for the firebase 9 syntax, but specifically, I want to use the 8 namespaced syntax.

```
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.10.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.10.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script type="module">
        import firebase from "firebase/app";
        // Add Firebase products that you want to use
        import "firebase/auth";
        import "firebase/storage";
        import "firebase/database";
```

Comment: Remove `type="module"` from the script tag and use the global `firebase` object - no need to use the import statements. Note: Using the legacy SDK version is not recommended as it no longer receives security updates nor can it use the new features such as the `getCount()` Firestore API and `startAfter`/`endBefore` RTDB query types. The last feature update was in July 2021.

Comment: You are loading scripts from html tags, so you cannot import them this way. There are no node_modules folder for referencing those modules, so you should provide full URL for your imports. Check firebase [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup)